# What is the entropy of binomial decay?

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution, entropy

Let's play a game. I start with $N$ tokens, and I wait $T$ turns. Every turn, each token has probability $p$ of disappearing. **I want an analytic formula for the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition) of this process, as a function of $N$, $T$, and $p$**.

The calculation is straightforward for $N=1$ and $T=\infty$. The probability $p_i$ that our (only) token disappears at turn $i$ is $(1-p)^{i}p$, and the entropy $E$ is given by:

$E(N=1, T=\infty, p=p) = \sum_{i}^{\infty}p_i\ln(p_i)$

$=\sum_{i}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i}p\ln((1-p)^{i}p)$

$=p\ln(1-p)\sum_{i}^{\infty}i(1-p)^{i} + p\ln(p)\sum_{i}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i}$

$=p\ln(1-p)\frac{1-p}{p^2} + p\ln(p)\frac{1}{p}$

$=\frac{1-p}{p}\ln(1-p) + \ln(p)$

For $N=2$ and $T=\infty$, my calculation (not shown) is a lot uglier, but simplifies down to:

$E(N=2, T=\infty, p=p) = \frac{2-2p}{2-p}\ln(2) + 2\ln(p) + \frac{2-2p}{p} \ln(1-p)$

I'm about to calculate the $N=3$, $T=\infty$ case, but I've got the feeling I'm reinventing the wheel. **Is the formula for $E(N, T, p)$ known?** I'm particularly interested in the $T=\infty$ case. A good approximation is almost as useful to me as an exact formula, but I'm interested in both small and large values of $N$.

As a sanity check, we can compare against a Python simulation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom

def entropy(n_initial, p, n_steps, n_trials):
    # Simulate many stochastic binomial decays, return the average of
    # the log of their binomial "penalty"
    log_penalty = np.zeros(n_trials, dtype=np.float64)
    n = n_initial * np.ones(n_trials, dtype=np.int64)
    for i in range(n_steps):
        num_losses = np.random.binomial(n, p)
        log_penalty += binom.logpmf(k=num_losses, n=n, p=p)
        n -= num_losses
    return log_penalty.mean()

p=0.1
print(entropy(n_initial=1, p=p, n_steps=1000, n_trials=10000))
print(((1-p)/p)*np.log(1-p) + np.log(p))

print(entropy(n_initial=2, p=p, n_steps=1000, n_trials=10000))
print((2-2*p)/(2-p)*np.log(2) + 2*np.log(p) + ((2-2*p)/p) * np.log(1-p))
```

Please forgive/correct me if I've made errors in my math or I'm using the wrong terms; I'm an experimental physicist, not a mathematician, and my formal math is rusty.

Comment: Your first example seem to be measuring the entropy of the time the single token disappears.  This is a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) and your value for the entropy is the same as Wikipedia's apart from (a) signs and (b) the base of the logarithm.  For your other examples it is not immediately clear what you are trying to measure the entropy of

Comment: Agreed about the geometric distribution. Good point about clarity, maybe you can help me improve? To calculate the $N=2$ case, I (tried to) enumerate all the ways two tokens could decay (first decay is a double decay on turn $t$, or first decay occurs at $t_{1}$ and second decay occurs at $t_{2}$), then I assign a probability $p_i$ to each possibility, then calculate $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}p_{i}\ln(p_{i})$. Did that clarify, or am I missing your point?

Comment: Do you mean you want to calculate the entropy of the maximum of $N$ i.i.d. geometric random variables with common parameter $p$?

Answer (score 2):

If $X_i\hookrightarrow \mathcal G(p)$ for $1\le i\le N$, and $T=\max_{1\le i\le N}(X_i)$, then it's easy to verify that for all $k\in\mathbb N^\ast$,
$$P(T\le k) = (1-q^k)^N$$
so
$$P(T=k)=(1-q^k)^N - (1-q^{k-1})^N=p_k$$
But I don't see how you could find a closed form for entropy of $T$ :
$$H(T)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k\log_2(p_k)$$
And this is only the case $T=\infty$...